# Set linetype for geom_vline?

Tags: r, ggplot2

For the following plot:

```
df.plot <-structure(list(color = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("54", "55", "61", "69"), class = "factor"), 
    date = structure(c(16687, 16687, 16687, 16687, 16687, 16687, 
    16688, 16688, 16688, 16689, 16689, 16690, 16693, 16693, 16693, 
    16694, 16694, 16695, 16695, 16695, 16695, 16696, 16696, 16696, 
    16696, 16696, 16696), class = "Date"), facet = c("A", 
     "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
     "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
     "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", 
     "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", 
     "C", "B", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -27L), 
     .Names = c("color", "date", "facet"))

vlines <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2015-09-10", "2015-09-13")), 
          LType=(c("AA", "AB")))
ggplot(df.plot, aes(x=date, fill=color)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binwidth=1, stackgroups=TRUE, binpositions="all") +
  coord_fixed(ratio=1) + 
  ylim(0,7) +
  geom_vline(data=vlines, aes(xintercept = as.numeric(date), linetype=LType))  + 
  facet_grid(facet ~ .)
```

I would like to make the line type for "AB" be "dotdash" , and for "AA" "longdash". How can I specify that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `scale_linetype_manual`.

```
library("ggplot2")
g0 <- ggplot(df.plot, aes(x=date, fill=color)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binwidth=1, stackgroups=TRUE, binpositions="all") +
  coord_fixed(ratio=1) + 
  ylim(0,7) +
  geom_vline(data=vlines, aes(xintercept = as.numeric(date), linetype=LType))  + 
  facet_grid(facet ~ .)
```

From `?par`:

> ‘lty’ The line type.  Line types can either be specified as an
>             integer (0=blank, 1=solid (default), 2=dashed, 3=dotted,
>             4=dotdash, 5=longdash, 6=twodash) or as one of the character
>             strings ‘"blank"’, ‘"solid"’, ‘"dashed"’, ‘"dotted"’,
>             ‘"dotdash"’, ‘"longdash"’, or ‘"twodash"’, where ‘"blank"’
>             uses ‘invisible lines’ (i.e., does not draw them).

So

```
g0 + scale_linetype_manual(values=c(5,4))
```

or (probably better!)

```
g0 + scale_linetype_manual(values=c("longdash","dotdash"))
```

---

If you are drawing a *single* vline, or if you are already using `scale_linetype_manual()` to specify line types for a `geom_line()`, it's easier/makes more sense to use `linetype` as an argument:

```
geom_vline(xintercept = <something>, linetype="dotdash")
```

Comment: While there's nothing wrong with this you can also add linetype as an argument. (e.g geom_vline(xintercept=0,color="grey",linetype="dashed",size=0.5)). This may be more convenient if you are already using scale_linetype_manual to specify lines added by geom_line().

Comment: but OP has two different vlines they want to draw (`aes(linetype=Ltype)`). You *could* use two separate `geom_vline` calls in a pinch, but that sort of subverts the ggplot paradigm ...

Comment: Just meant it as a potential alternative, connected to the general question: "Set linetype for geom_vline?". I'm assuming OP has solved his specific problem by now. Perhaps I should have phrased it differently.

Comment: I do prefer the simpler approach to include linetype as an argument in the geom_vline() wrapper.