# ggplot2 Legend Icon Mismatch for Horizontal and Vertical Lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the `iris` dataset in R with `ggplot2` to add horizontal and vertical lines to a scatter plot. My code is producing a dashed vertical line unintentionally and the legend icons are not reflecting the actual line types (horizontal or vertical). Here's the shortened version of the code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 4, lty = 'Horizontal'),
               color = 'steelblue', lwd = 2, key_glyph = 'path') +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 2, lty = 'Vertical'),
               color = 'firebrick', lwd = 2, key_glyph = 'path') +
    guides(lty = guide_legend(title = 'Lines',
                              override.aes = list(color = c('steelblue', 'firebrick'),
                              lty = c('solid', 'solid'))))
```

[image]

Why does the vertical line appear dashed, and how can I get the legend to show accurate icons for the horizontal and vertical lines?

I tried changing the vertical line `key_glyph`  to `vpath` without success.

Comment: See here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179844/set-linetype-for-geom-vline>

Comment: @TarJae thanks! and what about the having a vertical line icon for the vertical line legend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

key_glyph only controls what appears in the legend key. It shouldn't do anything to your plotted lines.

Similarly, the `guides` element only controls the aesthetics in the guide, not the plot.  Your legend was showing a solid line.

Below, I used `linetype` instead of `lty`, then controlled the appearance in the plot using `scale_linetype_manual` before adjusting the colours in the guide.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 4, linetype = "Horizontal"),
             color = 'steelblue', linewidth = 2, key_glyph = 'path') +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 2, linetype = "Veritcal"),
             color = 'firebrick', linewidth = 2, key_glyph = 'path') +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Lines", values = c("solid","solid")) +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(
                            override.aes = list(
                                                color = c('steelblue', 'firebrick'))))
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
Here is an adaptation from another workaround (very case specific) by @teunbrand https://stackoverflow.com/a/65799123

```
glyph_vline <- function(data, params, size) {
  if (data$colour == 'firebrick') {
    draw_key_vline(data, params, size)
  } else {
    zeroGrob()
  }
}

glyph_hline <- function(data, params, size) {
  if (data$colour == 'steelblue') {
    draw_key_path(data, params, size)
  } else {
     zeroGrob()
  }
}

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 4, linetype = "Horizontal"),
             color = 'steelblue', linewidth = 2, key_glyph = glyph_hline) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 2, linetype = "Veritcal"),
             color = 'firebrick', linewidth = 2, key_glyph = glyph_vline) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Lines", values = c("solid","solid")) +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(
                            override.aes = list(
                                                color = c('steelblue', 'firebrick')
                            )))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And what about the legend icons not reflecting the actual line types (horizontal or vertical)? I'd like the the vertical line icon to actually be a vertical line...

Comment: That's trickier and is a known issue.  I don't think there is a direct solution.  You can use a different key_glyph for each, but `ggplot` will combine them (`+` instead of `|` and `--` ).  There is a workaround here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66018655) that involves creating multiple keys. Not perfect, but it's an option.

Comment: See edit for another option by @teunbrand

Answer (score 3):

You can map to an unused aesthetic, such as `linewidth`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 4, lty = 'Horizontal'),
             color = 'steelblue', lwd = 2, key_glyph = 'path') +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 2, linewidth = 'Vertical'),
             color = 'firebrick', key_glyph = 'vline') +
  guides(color = guide_legend(order = 1),
         linewidth = guide_legend(title = NULL, order = 2),
         linetype = guide_legend(title = NULL, order = 3))
```

[image]